# I get an unautorized error when trying to use here maps routing service

Tags: here-api

I use api v3.1 and i am trying to calculate distance between 2 points

This is what i have

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
            type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
            type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': 'key'
      })
 const params = {
            mode: 'car;',
            waypoint0: lat1 + ',' + lon1,
            waypoint1: lat2 + ',' + lon2,
            representation: 'display',
            routeAttributes: 'summary'
          }

var routingService = platform.getRoutingService()
          routingService.calculateRoute(params, success => {
            console.log(success.response.route[0].summary)
          }, error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
```

But i get this error:

```
{
_type: "ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType",
type: "PermissionError",
subtype: "InvalidCredentials",
details: "Unauthorized. The request is not from an authorized source.",
metaInfo: {
timestamp: "2019-12-04T16:02:45Z",
mapVersion: "8.30.103.150",
moduleVersion: "7.2.201948-5874",
interfaceVersion: "2.6.74",
availableMapVersion: [
"8.30.103.150"
]
}
}
```

I tried with domain whitelist and without

Comment: Looks like app_id and app_key are not correctly passed. Does 'apikey' holds both app_id and app_key ??

Comment: Just the api_key. I followed this `https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/routing.html` and it doesn't say anything about app_id.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to execute this code .

var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'apikey': 'api_key'
    });
    //you can remove this if you dont want to see the map.
    var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

```
var map = new H.Map(
document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
maptypes.vector.normal.map,
{
  zoom: 10,
  center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
});
 // Till here

const params = {
           mode: 'fastest;car',
           waypoint0: '52.5160,13.3779',
           waypoint1: '52.5206,13.3862',
           representation: 'display',
           routeAttributes: 'summary'
         }
        function calcuateRouteFromAtoB(platform){
      
       var routingService = platform.getRoutingService()
        routingService.calculateRoute(params, success => {
      console.log(success.response.route[0].summary);
         }, error => {
      console.log(error);
         })
}
   calcuateRouteFromAtoB(platform);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working now, but i still have issues using it in a each statement. I have the first pair of coord from the user browser and then i have a list of items that i need to calculate the distance

Comment: The actual error is this ```Error: [] https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.8.1&apikey=api&mode=fastest%3Bcar&waypoint0=44.4512086%2C26.133909799999998&waypoint1=36.416807%2C28.146558&representation=display&routeAttributes=summary request failed
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (mapsjs-core.js:66), <anonymous>:63:181)```

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely problem with your apikey. Either it's not valid, or they way how you insert is not correct.

I tried your code with my apikey and it looks good (just replace 'your_apikey_string' with your own apikey value):

```
const apikey = 'your_apikey_string';

var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  'apikey': apikey
})

var params = {
  mode: 'fastest;car',
  waypoint0: 49 + ',' + 19,
  waypoint1: 49 + ',' + 19.5,
  representation: 'display',
  routeAttributes: 'summary'
}

var routingService = platform.getRoutingService()

routingService.calculateRoute(params, success => {
  console.log(success.response.route[0].summary)
}, error => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: if i try this is not working ```window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
          console.log('coord')
          var lat = Number(pos.coords.latitude)
          var lon = Number(pos.coords.longitude)

          const params = {
            mode: 'fastest;car',
            waypoint0: '44.4512086,26.133909799999998',
            waypoint1: '36.416807,28.146558',
            representation: 'display',
            routeAttributes: 'summary'
          }
          console.log(params)
         
          calcuateRouteFromAtoB(params)

        })```

Comment: What exactly is not working? I am little bit lost now.
Is it possible that you maybe share your page?

Comment: The project is not live yet. If i call the function to calculate from the browser getCurrentPosition function i get ```Error: [] https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.8.1&apikey=api&mode=fastest%3Bcar&waypoint0=44.4512086%2C26.133909799999998&waypoint1=36.416807%2C28.146558&representation=display&routeAttributes=summary request failed
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (mapsjs-core.js:66), <anonymous>:63:181)``` But if i call it outside of any custom functions it's working

Comment: But this is different error, right? The initial question was about unauthorized error. Has this problem been solved already?